# Redirecting from subfolder to subdomain

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, proxy, url-rewriting

Right now I have web api configured for my route `web.site.com/v1/api`. The subdomain `api.site.com` currently points to `web.site.com`. Is there any way to route requests made to `api.site.com` to `web.site.com/v1/api`, without redirects? I.e. I don't want to user to know they're actually sending requests to `web.site.com/v1/api`.

Is a rewrite rule with proxy the way to go here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both are same application,you can just rewrite only the URL part to  **v1/api/{R:1}**

This rule should work.

```
<rule name="rewriteochildifapi">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="api.example.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="v1/api/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```